# webdriverio: SevereServiceError: Couldn't start Chromedriver: timeout Please check if port 9515 is in use

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I am learning how to use webdriver io, I have installed the necessary packages, but when I run the command to test, I get the error that the port may already be in use.

**Full logs**

```
npm run wdio

> webdriverio-tests@0.1.0 wdio
> wdio run wdio.conf.js


Execution of 1 workers started at 2022-03-14T18:56:58.789Z

2022-03-14T18:56:58.810Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onPrepare hook
2022-03-14T18:56:58.811Z INFO chromedriver: Start Chromedriver (/home/davidshare/Documents/davidshare/QA/webdriverio-test/node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver/chromedriver) with args --port=9515 --url-base=/
2022-03-14T18:56:58.820Z INFO chromedriver: Starting ChromeDriver 99.0.4844.51 (d537ec02474b5afe23684e7963d538896c63ac77-refs/branch-heads/4844@{#875}) on port 9515
2022-03-14T18:56:58.821Z INFO chromedriver: Only local connections are allowed.
2022-03-14T18:56:58.821Z INFO chromedriver: Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
2022-03-14T18:56:58.821Z INFO chromedriver: ChromeDriver was started successfully.
2022-03-14T18:57:08.818Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Shutting down spawned worker
2022-03-14T18:57:09.070Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Waiting for 0 to shut down gracefully
2022-03-14T18:57:09.071Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: shutting down
Error: 
A service failed in the 'onPrepare' hook
SevereServiceError: Couldn't start Chromedriver: timeout
Please check if port 9515 is in use!
    at ChromeDriverLauncher.onPrepare (/home/davidshare/Documents/davidshare/QA/webdriverio-test/node_modules/wdio-chromedriver-service/build/launcher.js:96:13)
    at async /home/davidshare/Documents/davidshare/QA/webdriverio-test/node_modules/@wdio/cli/build/utils.js:28:17
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async Launcher.run (/home/davidshare/Documents/davidshare/QA/webdriverio-test/node_modules/@wdio/cli/build/launcher.js:86:13)



Stopping runner...
    at /home/davidshare/Documents/davidshare/QA/webdriverio-test/node_modules/@wdio/cli/build/utils.js:44:35
    at async Launcher.run (/home/davidshare/Documents/davidshare/QA/webdriverio-test/node_modules/@wdio/cli/build/launcher.js:86:13)
```

When I run the `netstat -tulpn` command, I see that chrome driver is the one using the port. But even when I kill the process using the pid and then run the command again, I still get the same error.

Please I need help with this.

```
node --version
v16.13.0
```

```
Google Chrome 99.0.4844.51
```

Answer (score 2):

This is bug with "wdio-chromedriver-service": "7.3.0". It was released a day ago. Try using previous version "7.2.8" in package.json.

Comment: Could you please link the bug report for it?

Comment: I reported the bug: https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/8522
7.2.8 is also working for me

Answer (score 2):

Kill the processes that are running in that port and then try to execute (solution for linux machine).

`lsof -i:9515` - Will list all active process(s) listening to `9515` port.

`kill $(lsof -t -i:9515)` - This will kill all the process(s).

This worked for me. - Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me : for  "devDependencies": {
        "@wdio/cli": "^7.25.2",
        "@wdio/cucumber-framework": "^7.25.1",
        "@wdio/local-runner": "^7.25.2",
        "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^7.25.1",
        "chromedriver": "^106.0.1",
        "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
        "typescript": "^4.8.4",
        "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^8.0.0"
    }

Answer (score 1):

Tried with version "wdio-chromedriver-service": "7.2.8" in package.json, Working fine

Answer (score 0):

Update with the previous version of chrome then run npm install fix the problem.
"chromedriver": "^98.0.0",